# How to include values from two tables in a one to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've been beating around on this thing all day and it's driving me nuts!

What I'm trying to do:

I have 2 tables: Questions / Answers

The questions table consists of: quesID, quesDescr
The answers table consists of: answerID, quesID, answer

Basically, the answers table are the options for each question. For example:

quesID | quesDescr

1 | What is your favorite color?

answerID | quesID | answer

1 | 1 | Red

2 | 1 | Blue

etc...

On my form page I want to grab the questions and all their answer choices to display to the end user. It seems I can get the questions to list but I can't get both the questions and answers to post on my View.

I thought I would handle the query (linq to sql) in my model... but this doesn't give me the answers:

```
public List<nonEEPreQue> getPreQuestions()
        {
            return fDB.nonEEPreQues.OrderBy(q => q.preQuesOrder).ToList();
        }
```

I read some things here and across that web that use outer joins. I think this might be correct, but I'm struggling with how to pass the variable. I tried this in the Model, but it seems it goes into the controller(?):

```
var quesList = from ques in preQ.nonEEPreQues
                       join an in preQ.nonEEPreQuesAnswers
                        on ques.preQuesID equals an.preQuesID into outer
                       from an in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new
                       {
                           QuestionTxt = ques.preQuesDescr,
                            AnswerTxt = an.answerTxt
                       };


        return View(quesList);
```

So - is the above correct?  What do I do then in my view to access both question and answers (I assume in a foreach loop)?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using Linq to SQL and using an anonymous type, keep it simple and select what you need in a relational manner.

```
var quesList = from ques in preQ.nonEEPreQues
               select new
               {
                   QuestionID = ques.preQuesID,
                   QuestionTxt = ques.preQuesDescr,
                   Answers = (from  an in preQ.nonEEPreQuesAnswers
                              where an.preQuesID == ques.preQuesID
                              select an)
               };
```

This will give you an object that has QuestionTxt and QuestionID for the questions and a collection of `nonEEPreQuesAnswer` objects that are attached to question directly. This will make enumerating them easier, and it should be bindable as well (if you were doing a gridview or repeater).

Comment: Hi Joel - what model declaration would I need on my view for this?

Comment: @EddieWesley: My assumption is that you would build your own model to handle this that would be typed in this manner. This sample uses an anonymous type, but a prebuilt model would make it easier.

Comment: Thanks - I'll play with this a bit. I'm not married to what I posted - I really want to take the best approach here. I'm even considering using stored procedures if that would make more sense. I have a dbml model and would love to utilize that if possible

Comment: @EddieWesley: I use the classes auto-generated by importing my tables into my dbml whenever possible. So far, the things that my dbml classes haven't supported I've been able to able to accomplish with a custom model.

Comment: Thanks. So - where I'm stuck is the view. Taking your example above, that can be in my model code file.. or my controller? Would this be passed to the view as an IEnumerable?  I'm sorry if these might be obvious, this is just my 2nd project.

Comment: @EddieWesley: It definitely shouldn't be in your controller. The controller is for marshalling models, etc. My recommendation would be to create a model that supports this structure, and then set up a data access class that is responsible for populating the model so your controller would have something like `return View(dataAccessClass.GetQuestionsAndAnswers());` where the method is what is above.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getPreQuestions()` you should query for answers and using `Include()` include the questions.

This will retrieve a list of answers with a property loaded with the Questions... you then pass that list to the view.

Comment: Thanks, Romias. Unfortunately I don't think Include() is available for Linq to SQL ?